# How to change image size in impresspages 4 slider plugin?

Tags: image, slider, size, impresspages

just installed the plugin and have no idea how and where i can change image size. It does not have any options in "plugin configurations" to change. In one file im able to change the speed but thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now only solution is to make changes in Controller.php (Plugin/Slider/Widget/Slider), just put needed dimensions there and it works perfectly:

```
207 $transformBig = array(
208    'type' => 'fit',
209    'width' => 1000,
210    'height' => 330
211 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this particular slider. But it is widget based. That means it likely takes 100% width of area where it is dropped.

Comment: If it would just take 100% its good enough for me but it's not doing that at all. I found solution and posted it above.